# How to Display BuddyPress Profile Field Data In Multisite Blogs

Tags: multisite, buddypress

I'm trying to display a BuddyPress xprofile field on a WordPress multsite blog. I thought this might do the trick but displayed_user doesn't seem to work outside of BP? Is there an easy way to do this? I know there's an [old plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-profile-widget-for-blogs/) that does it in a widget but I don't really need all of that and would rather put this directly in the theme.

Here's what I've tried within the theme on the multisite blog. This works with loggedin_user->id but of course what I'm shooting for is the profile data for the blog admin. Is that possible to fetch?

```
<?php 
global $bp;
$myfield = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Counties Served', $bp->displayed_user->id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
$data = xprofile_format_profile_field('checkbox', $myfield);
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$bp->displayed_user->id` returns the same id as the author id so when you are not inside a members loop or on a members page you have to get the user id using WordPress functions.

```
<?php 
global $bp, $post;
$myfield = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Counties Served', $post->post_author, $multi_format = 'comma' );
$data = xprofile_format_profile_field('checkbox', $myfield);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @modemlooper. For some reason your solution didn't work for me - not sure why but it was pulling the super admin's ID instead. Nevertheless, this put me on the right track. I'll post what worked below.

Comment: I just wrote that off top of my head, glad you found something to work.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit more, here's what finally worked for me:

```
global $bp;
$thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;
$user_from_email = get_user_by('email', get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email'));
$user_id = $user_from_email->ID;
$myfield = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Counties Served', $user_id, $multi_format = 'comma' );
$data = xprofile_format_profile_field('checkbox', $myfield);
echo $data;
```